# How can I write a function that parses nested strings with brackets and turns them into an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that parses strings like the following

```
GEYDQORRGM5D[C[M[A,I,Q,Y],NA],O,Q,S]
```

and turns it into an array like the following

```js
[
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMA",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMI",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMQ",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMY",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCNA",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DO",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DQ",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DS",
]
```

I've tried the following code and it works for some of the strings but most of them don't work!!

```js
function splitAndAddString() {
    let regex = /([A-Z0-9]+)(?:\[([A-Z,]+)\])?/g
    const result = []

    let match;
    while ((match = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
        const prefix = match[1];
        const suffixes = match[2] ? match[2].split(",") : [""];
        for (const suffix of suffixes) {
            result.push(prefix + suffix);
        }
    }


    const newResult = []
    for (let i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
        newResult.push(result[0] + result[i])
    }

    return newResult
}

const input = 'GEYDQORRGM5D[C[M[A,I,Q,Y],NA],O,Q,S]';
const output = splitAndAddString(input);
console.log(output);
```

it returns

```js
[
  "GEYDQORRGM5DC",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DMA",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DMI",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DMQ",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DMY",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DNA",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DO",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DQ",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DS",
]
```

when its supposed to return

```js
[
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMA",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMI",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMQ",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCMY",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DCNA",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DO",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DQ",
  "GEYDQORRGM5DS",
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It is not returning what it needs to return, I've tried at least 6 or 7 functions to pull this off but I cannot get it to work

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Start your code in the debugger and step line by line through the code until something unexpected happens. Ask a specific programming question about this observation.

Comment: This is a fun problem, I disagree with the downvotes. I would probably to do it recursively, turn your input string into a tree, then flatten the tree into the output.

Comment: @AndyRay I downvoted because [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Debugging falls into the category troubleshoot. _"This is my code. Why does it not work"_ is usually not helpful for other users and therefore downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex can only deal with one level of bracket nesting. Instead deal with the `[` and `]` tokens separately, so you can make a recursive call when encountering `[`, and unwind when encountering `]`.

This is also a nice candidate for a generator:

```js
function getProductions(s) {
    const tokens = s.split(/([[,\]])/).values();

    function* dfs() {
        while (true) {
            const {value} = tokens.next();
            const token = tokens.next().value ?? "]";
            if ("],".includes(token) && value) yield value;
            if (token == "]") return;
            if (token == "[") {
                for (const postfix of dfs()) {
                    yield value + postfix;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return [...dfs()];
}

// Demo run on your example:
const s = "GEYDQORRGM5D[C[M[A,I,Q,Y],NA],O,Q,S]"
console.log(getProductions(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function that can be called recursively with a subset of the string.

I added comments in the code to explain what happens.

```js
function splitAndAddString(str) {
  let regex = /^([A-Z0-9]+)\[(.*)\]([A-Z0-9,]*)$/
  let result = [];

  let match = regex.exec(str);
  if (match) {
    let prefix = match[1]; // before first [
    let between = match[2]; // between first [ and last ]
    let suffix = match[3]; // after the last ]
    
    // call splitAndAddString requesive with between
    // and map the result with the current prefix
    let nested = splitAndAddString(between).map(str => prefix + str);
    result = result.concat(nested); // add to result
    
    // if suffix is a string with commas
    // and filter out empty strings from the array
    let suffixes = suffix.split(',').filter(str => str.length > 0);
    result = result.concat(suffixes); // add to result
  } else {
    // if match is NULL there can be a string with commas
    result = str.split(',').filter(str => str.length > 0);
  }
  return result;
}

const input = 'GEYDQORRGM5D[C[M[A,I,Q,Y],NA],O,Q,S]';
const output = splitAndAddString(input);
console.log(output);
```